# Artifactory UI download OK, npm install fail with auth error

Tags: npm-install, artifactory

How do we get scoped repo using artifactory?

- setup npm.fontawesome.com remote repo in artifactory according to the [doc](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-how-to-configure-a-remote-npm-repository-to-proxy-fontawesome/)
- used username TOKEN and password - the actual token
- auth check in UI **OK**
- listing of @fortawesome/angular-fontawesome visible in UI
- download of artifact via uI OK
- npm rc defines scoped repo

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://artifactory/artifactory/api/npm/npm-fontawesome.com-remote/
```

Anonymous access granted to 3rdparty repo for users in my env - build machines included

npm -i fails with auth where the system looks to be going directly do npm.fontawesome.com and not my artifactory repo

```
2999 verbose stack HttpErrorAuthUnknown: Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="https://npm.fontawesome.com/",service="npm.fontawesome.com"
2999 verbose stack at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/check-response.js:80:17
2999 verbose stack at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alas, use of token auth for npm repos is not yet supported by jfrog artifactory (see [RTFACT-19164](https://jfrog.atlassian.net/browse/RTFACT-19164))